# I am creating events using microsoft graph (using .net sdk) and i found out that 2 events have same id with in a mailbox

Tags: graph, calendar

Is this a valid scenario or a bug? Both the events are copied below.

{
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"xyy/ioMMpU+5PhLPRGcb5AAAHWKktw==\"",
            "id": "AAMkADZlNDUzMDYxLTQ2OTEtNDNiOC1hMDNhLTY1ZjAyMTYwZTBkOQBGAAAAAACPfBk217UgTYo6zKN7dzZsBwDHLL_KgwylT7k_Es9EZxvkAAAAAAENAADHLL_KgwylT7k_Es9EZxvkAAAdZ_YbAAA=",
            "subject": "TestUtilityRunNow7_51",
            "bodyPreview": "",
            "body": {
                "contentType": "html",
                "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n"
            },
            "start": {
                "dateTime": "2019-03-08T12:57:15.0000000",
                "timeZone": "UTC"
            },
            "end": {
                "dateTime": "2019-03-08T13:02:15.0000000",
                "timeZone": "UTC"
            },
            "location": {
                "displayName": "",
                "locationType": "default",
                "uniqueIdType": "unknown",
                "address": {},
                "coordinates": {}
            },
            "attendees": [
                {
                    "type": "resource",
                    "status": {
                        "response": "none",
                        "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
                    },
                    "emailAddress": {
                        "name": "Training Room",
                        "address": "trainingroom@wmexchangeid.onmicrosoft.com"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "organizer": {
                "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "Ravinder Singh Chahal",
                    "address": "ravindersingh.chahal@wmexchangeid.onmicrosoft.com"
                }
            }
        }

{
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"xyy/ioMMpU+5PhLPRGcb5AAAHWKiVA==\"",
            "id": "AAMkADZlNDUzMDYxLTQ2OTEtNDNiOC1hMDNhLTY1ZjAyMTYwZTBkOQBGAAAAAACPfBk217UgTYo6zKN7dzZsBwDHLL_KgwylT7k_Es9EZxvkAAAAAAENAADHLL_KgwylT7k_Es9EZxvkAAAdZ_YBAAA=",
            "subject": "TestUtilityRunNow7_25",
            "bodyPreview": "",
            "body": {
                "contentType": "html",
                "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n"
            },
            "start": {
                "dateTime": "2019-03-08T12:30:59.0000000",
                "timeZone": "UTC"
            },
            "end": {
                "dateTime": "2019-03-08T12:35:59.0000000",
                "timeZone": "UTC"
            },
            "location": {
                "displayName": "",
                "locationType": "default",
                "uniqueIdType": "unknown",
                "address": {},
                "coordinates": {}
            },
            "attendees": [
                {
                    "type": "resource",
                    "status": {
                        "response": "none",
                        "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
                    },
                    "emailAddress": {
                        "name": "Training Room",
                        "address": "trainingroom@wmexchangeid.onmicrosoft.com"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "organizer": {
                "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "Ravinder Singh Chahal",
                    "address": "ravindersingh.chahal@wmexchangeid.onmicrosoft.com"
                }
            }
        }

Comment: Sorry my bad, the difference is there but in the casing.